# Does Hibernate solve object relational impedance mismatch?

Tags: hibernate, orm

What problems does JDBC have regarding this paradigm mismatch, which are resolved by Hibernate?

Answer (score 2):

The object relational impedance mismatch is about difference between objects in OOP paradigm and rows in relational databases. In database there are no object so we can't save our objects to database easily.

We can solve this mismatch by ORM(Object relational mapping). It's when you write mapping *object's field* -> *column*.

> What problems JDBC created?

JDBC didn't create problems it is just the standard API that Java applications use to interact with a database. It's the most basic way to perform ORM.

Hibernate just more simple and conveniet to use then JDBC although Hibernate uses JDBC internally to communicate with a database.

What the benefits are of hibernate over JDBC?
**a**. Hibernate can be used seamlessly with any type of database as its database independent while in case of JDBC, developer has to write database specific queries.
**b**. Using hibernate, developer doesn’t need to be an expert of writing complex queries as HQL simplifies query writing process while in case of JDBC, its job of developer to write and tune queries.
**c**. In case of hibernate, there is no need to create connection pools as hibernate does all connection handling automatically while in case of JDBC, connection pools need to be created.